# Get COM port number of usb serial FTDI

Tags: batch-file, registry, usbserial, ftdi

I have a FTDI usb-serial and I am interested in the getting the COM port assigned to the device on `USB serial converter A`. Is there a way I can list this information programatically (say cmd) to extract the COM port number that corresponds to the one at that location. I can view this information in the device manager properties, so there could be a way to get this information through a script I guess? I am certain the COM port I would connect to will be on the serial converter A.
I was looking up the registry entries for the usb device and the device I want to connect to goes to VCP0. to narrow down my question, whats the best way to get the COM number from query-ing `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM`

which gives me:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM  
\Device\VCP0    REG_SZ    COM9                                                                                                                                                      
\Device\VCP1    REG_SZ    COM10
```

EDIT: I am trying to get the value of data for `\Device\VCP0` using this command, but I think I am not escaping backslashes correctly:

`REG QUERY "HKLM:\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM" /v "\\Device\\VCP0"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "CDev=VCP0"
Set "RKey=HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM"
Set "CNum="
For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=3" %%A In (
    'Reg Query "%RKey%" /V "\Device\%CDev%" 2^>Nul') Do Set CNum=%%A
If Not Defined CNum Exit /B
Rem Your commands below here
Echo %CNum%
Timeout 5 >Nul
```

*You should only ever need to modify the device name on line `2` and place any of your own commands beneath from the `Rem` line.*

Possible corrections for your straight query command are either:

```bat
Reg Query "HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM" /V "\Device\VCP0"
```

Or:

```bat
Reg Query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM" /V "\Device\VCP0"
```

*There was no need to escape the backslashes in the device name, and a little confusion in root key syntax*

Comment: Ah I see, so the problem is that I am adding the `HKLM` in front of the path? And I don't need to escape backslashes. The for loop is pretty nifty, care to explain what the `Skip=1 Tokens=3` is doing?

Comment: Actually the entire for loop looks foreign to me, it'd be great if you can provide some background

Comment: I have added corrections for your straight registry query commands to the bottom of my answer.